# How to make db values work inside a jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a query plugin slider which looks similar to facebook like photogrid. I have a `mysqli_fetch_array` which brings the image paths from a field called `contentimage`(which holds a string of the multiple image's paths separated by comma,"https://unsplash.it/660/440?image=875,https://unsplash.it/660/455?image=838,"). Though the script is working with the images: array in the script. How to include the db values inside the jquery ?

```
<div class="post-image">
                        <div id="gallery7"></div>
                   <script>

               $(function() {


            $('#gallery7').imagesGrid({
                images: [
   'https://unsplash.it/660/440?image=875',
       'https://unsplash.it/660/455?image=838',
      'https://unsplash.it/660/990?image=874',
       'https://unsplash.it/660/440?image=872',
        'https://unsplash.it/660/990?image=839',
          'https://unsplash.it/750/500?image=868' ],
                align: true,
                getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
            });

        });

    </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a hidden input to hold the image path value.
Try this

```
<div class="post-image">
    <?php $imagePathArray = explode(',', $imagePathString); ?>
    <input id="img-paths" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($imagePathArray)); ?>" />
                        <div id="gallery7"></div>
                   <script>

               $(function() {


            $('#gallery7').imagesGrid({
                images: $.parseJSON($('#img-paths').val()),
                align: true,
                getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
            });

        });

    </script>
    </div>
```

**Explanation**

Use `$imagePathArray = explode(',', $imagePathString);` to convert image path string into array. [Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for further explanation about `explode()`.

Then we convert the array into json string using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): `json_encode($imagePathArray)`.

After we get the json representation of the array, we store it inside a hidden input field: `<input id="img-paths" type="hidden" value="<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($imagePathArray)); ?>" />`. By the way, `htmlentities()` is used to prevent html from breaking because of special characters in json string.

Finally, we grab the json string in javascript and parse the string back to array:

```
$('#gallery7').imagesGrid({
                    images: $.parseJSON($('#img-paths').val()),
                    align: true,
                    getViewAllText: function(imgsCount) { return 'View all' }
                });
```

Comment: thnks a lot it is wrking .. My application has feature similar to facebook and linkedin in ehich there are Posts ..each posts may have these pics slider.. This slider works only for one post. if i refresh the page all posts doesnt have the images..except one post. how to resolve that ? @Bondan

Comment: There are some ways to to achieve your goal. One of them is to number id of the hidden input. In this case change `<input id="img-paths"` to  `<input id="img-path-7"`, also don't forget to change the javascript `$('#img-paths').val()` to `$('#img-path-7').val()`. Just number every hidden input accordingly @sayuj3

Comment: @Bondon Sebastian Yeah i got near to your solution. But i have $msg_id which also is a field from database for each message posts.can i write like this $('#img-path-<?php echo $msg_id;?>').val().?

Comment: Yes you can, just don't forget to update the hidden input field accordingly, eg: `<input id="img-path-<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" ...` @sayuj3

Comment: yeah its working fine thanks for the help @Bondon Sebastian